# Eclipse mars Installation folder in Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos

I need the Eclipse Installation folder, it was requested from another program, but there is no such a folder. When I installed eclipse I did not get any folder out of the compressed file, I only get the program itself. 
However, I copied the contents and it says " it's not the installation folder since it does not have "plugins" subfolder.
[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnPM8.png)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new path for the plugins is
/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins

Comment: It did work when i copied the contents of eclipse and reached the target file for there. but it did not get connected to eclipse. I guess because it is a copy. But is there another way to reach it ?

Comment: This is so incorrect answer, why is it accepted as correct answer? The path for Eclipse is the path you have chosen to install Eclipse. You can't just assume that it will be in the Applications folder. the answer below by moonlighter is the correct and 100% certain way to find the installation directory.

Answer (score 4):

The eclipse will be installed where you decided to put it not always under /Applications necessarily. The easiest way I think to find the installation folder is to run eclipse, go to Eclipse > About Eclipse. Click "Installation Details" at the bottom. The configuration tab in installation details should have the location of eclipse for launcher and startup config. Hope this helps!

Comment: From the above description, I found my launcher to be at /Users/pnutalap/Desktop/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse. When I choose that place as the installation in the Lombok installer, I get the message saying that 
"I can't find any IDE that Lombok supports at location /Users/pnutalap/Desktop/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse

I am using Eclipse Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)
Build id: 20190917-1200
and Lombok -1.18.1.jar file

Any suggestions ?

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

In mac os you need to select the eclipse ini file  not ecllipse.app

Comment: This info is helpful for locating installation directory for Lombok

Comment: No, it is not under Applications